# Hiding/showing SSPullToRefresh when necessary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my UI I have `UITableView` which is scrolling right behind the `UISearchBar` and `UINavigationBar` so you can see a little bluriness on those components. This is pretty nice but I have also implemented `SSPullToRefresh` and it's constantly hiding (visible in some way) behind those two... So it is not a pretty effect!

I was hoping to hide `SSPullToResfresh` when it's not visible and show it again when user scroll to it again. Hiding is easy with `setHidden:YES` but it is not working correctly. Of course there are `SSPullToRefreshViewStates` but when I try to hide this view in any state there is no effect... 
So I thought about the other solution `pullToRefreshViewDidStartLoading:` but in that case the view is being hidden/showed when refresh action start performing (not when it's showing so it's too late) and I don't know if there is the opposite method to perform hiding when `SSPullToRefresh` disappears.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is intrested in that matter it is impossible for now to show/hide `SSPullToRefresh`. You can find proper issue on [github page](https://github.com/soffes/sspulltorefresh/issues?state=closed).